# My Rails App works on localhost but not on Heroku

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, heroku, modal-dialog

I'm new to rails and currently I have a working Rails App which works perfectly on localhost but when I deployed it into Heroku.com I can still see the home page and as I navigate to another page it shows me the error. I tried using this command "heroku logs"

Here the logs

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `link_to_modal' for #<#<Class:0x000000046b8a10>:0x000000046b4500>):
```

Could it be the reason that I have 'link_to_modal' method in my view ??

```
<p class="text"><%= link_to_modal "+Add Album", "#addalbum" %><p>
```

It works perfectly normally on my computer but not on heroku so I'm wondering what can I do with that and this method came with this gem that I'm using ["jquery-modal-rails"](https://github.com/dei79/jquery-modal-rails)

Comment: did you use bundler to install the jquery-modal-rails gem? i.e. did you add it to your `Gemfile` ?

Comment: yes, I did and everything works alright locally but not on Heroku

Answer (score 2):

Add these lines to your config/production.rb file

```
require 'jquery/modal/rails'
require 'jquery/modal/filters'
require 'jquery/modal/helpers'
```